# Why am I getting this error "block is not defined"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting this javascript error: "block is not defined"

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $(".register_now").click(function()
  {

    $(".fp_top_right_login").slideToggle(600);
    var st = document.getElementById("fp_top_right_register").style.display;
    if(st == "" || st == "none")
    {
      window.setTimeout(document.getElementById("fp_top_right_register").style.display="block",600); //error happens here
    }
    else
    {
      window.setTimeout(document.getElementById("fp_top_right_register").style.display="none",600); //and also here
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you make a JsFiddle with a testcase of the problem?

Comment: So no one else has yet asked why you're using "getElementById" right next to a jQuery selector?  Use `$('#foo')` instead!

Comment: Why are you using `document.getElementById("fp_top_right_register").style.display="block"` when you're using jQuery anyway? `$("#fp_top_right_register").show()` isn't any faster, but it's a lot shorter and easier to read.

Comment: This code wasn't written by me, I'm just fixing things on our site

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`setTimeout` takes a function as a parameter. You can use an anonymous function. Example:

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("fp_top_right_register").style.display="block"; 
}, 600);
```

Comment: `setTimeout` can also take a string literal as code to be executed, but you should *never do this*.  Using a function is always the better option.

Answer (score 3):

There is an error in you way of using setTimeout.

```
window.setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById("fp_top_right_register").style.display="block"},600);
```

Also, consider using [jquery css](http://api.jquery.com/css/) :

```
$('#fp_top_right_register').css('display','block');
```

Answer (score 0):

The first argument to `window.setTimeout` should be a function, not a string, which is the result of your assignment.

You probably wanted to wrap that assignment in

```
function () { .... }
```